# Disable check box only works first time

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, checkbox

Im passing a list of orders to my view and displaying them on screen:

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.AllOrders.Count; i++)
     {
    <text>
       <tr>
            <td width="15%">@Model.AllOrders[i].CustomerName</td>   
            <td width="15%">@Model.AllOrders[i].CustomerAddress</td>
            <td width="15%">@Model.AllOrders[i].CustomerPhoneNumber</td>
            <td width="15%">@Model.AllOrders[i].CustomerEmail</td>
            <td width="15%">@Model.ModelBikeMapping[@Model.AllOrders[i].BicycleModel]</td>
            <td width="15%">@Model.SizeMapping[@Model.AllOrders[i].BicycleSize]</td>
            <td width="15%">@Model.ColourMapping[@Model.AllOrders[i].BicycleColour]</td>
            <td width="15%">@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => @Model.AllOrders[i].Shipped)</td>

            <td width="15%">@Html.HiddenFor(item => Model.AllOrders[i].CustomerName)</td>
            <td width="15%">@Html.HiddenFor(item => Model.AllOrders[i].CustomerAddress)</td>
            <td width="15%">@Html.HiddenFor(item => Model.AllOrders[i].CustomerPhoneNumber)</td>
            <td width="15%">@Html.HiddenFor(item => Model.AllOrders[i].CustomerEmail)</td>
            <td width="15%">@Html.HiddenFor(item => Model.AllOrders[i].BicycleModel)</td>
            <td width="15%">@Html.HiddenFor(item => Model.AllOrders[i].BicycleSize)</td>
            <td width="15%">@Html.HiddenFor(item => Model.AllOrders[i].BicycleColour)</td>
            <td width="15%">@Html.HiddenFor(item => Model.AllOrders[i].Shipped)</td>              
       </tr>
    </text>
     }   

</table>
 <p>
     <input type="submit" value="Update" />
 </p>
```

From here the user can check or uncheck the 'Shipped' check box and click 'Update' which passes the new 'shipped' value back to the controller which updates the db table.
This all works fine. However if the check box is TRUE I want to disable it as you can only ship an item once.

iv tried:

```
@if (@Model.AllOrders[i].Shipped)
            {
                <td width="15%">@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => @Model.AllOrders[i].Shipped, new { disabled = "disabled" })</td>
                <td width="15%">@Html.HiddenFor(item => Model.AllOrders[i].Shipped)</td>  
            }
            else
            {
                <td width="15%">@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => @Model.AllOrders[i].Shipped)</td>
                <td width="15%">@Html.HiddenFor(item => Model.AllOrders[i].Shipped)</td>  
            }
```

The problem with this is that the user can update a new record from unshipped[F] to shipped[T] and the db updates correctly but all existing TRUE 'shipped' values are passed back as FALSE'unshipped' to the controller. Is it something to do with my logic, or passing the hiddenFor?
Please advise

Comment: two thoughts here, 1. can you show your post logic for the update and 2. why do you have a HiddenFor for the checkbox?  The CheckBoxFor should be sufficient

Comment: Thanks for reply Niko....I Had to include a hidden field to pass back the value to the POST, while the checkBoxFor displays the value on screen. My post logic for the update works fine because if I dont disable the checkbox it all works. its only when I try to disable checkboxes that are already selected is when they are posted back to the POST as FALSE instead of TRUE

Comment: What does your model look like?  Is it just a container for your list of Orders?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is the way the model binder is interacting with your model.

Based on what I'm seeing I would expect your model to look something like

```
public class ModelType
{
public List<Order> AllOrders {get; set;}
}
```

When you try to loop through this in your form and post it back to the server, it gets a little funky.  The quickest and easiest way to fix this is to add a property to your Model then putting that in as a hidden field on your form.

```
public class ModelType
{
public List<Order> AllOrders {get; set;}
public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

Then add Id to your form as a hidden value.

I believe the proper way to fix this is to use the Html.EditorFor in which you would remove your for loop and replace it with your editor.  I have run into some weirdness with the editor too, mostly with the fact that it wants to be named the same as your T from the List and be in the shared folder.  But I would recommend looking into it, however adding that Id prop (or any other really) should be a quick fix for you.

Comment: thank you for the reply. yes I realise what you are saying I have used something similar in the past to resolve another issue....but this still doesnt explain why when the page loads and all the previous check boxes which WERE TRUE, therefore disabled. Are passed back to the POST as FALSE, when it should be TRUE. Similiary if I remove the disabled check boxes for TRUE and just display as normal, the correct value is sent back to the post, TRUE for checked, FALSE for unchecked

Comment: Are you saying it works as intended if you remove the disabled attribute or the checkbox itself

Comment: yes it all works fine if I remove the disabled attribute. But as I want to disable the checkbox if it is ever selected I have added in the @if (@Model.AllOrders[i].Shipped)(check orignal post), //if true disable, if false allow user to CHECK box....but as I said when I use this all the existing checked vales are passed back as FALSE, when they should be TRUE